# How do I properly introduce non-English text in an English Essay?

Tags: foreign-phrases

I want to insert a quote from an Indian book in Sanskrit and I currently have it formatted like this:

> In this book, one verse goes "Vadhikaraste ma phaleshu" or "It is your duty to help others."

Is this the correct way of introducing the non-English text? Do I need to italicize anything?

Comment: It depends on who you're writing for, and what kind of publication (if any) is involved. There may be standards if there's an editor. If not, use your own judgement -- what looks right to **you**? Personally, I would italicize the Sanskrit to emphasize that it's not English spelling; if you italicize, quotes are not necessary.

Comment: Don't use "or" to indicate "which can be translated as".  Generally, be explicit.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *or,* at least in British English.

Answer (score 6):

No italics are necessary in your example. You're making a direct quote of the verse and its translation.

It would be right to italicise a foreign word when it's used as though it were an English word, say in something like

> In this book, one *pāda* goes "Vadhikaraste ma phaleshu" or "It is your duty to help others."

...and in that case, where you are italicising Sanskrit, you **could** italicise the Sanskrit phrase.

---

[I'm not sure that *pāda* is the right word, but it serves the purpose for this answer. The phrase "Karmanye vadhikaraste Ma Phaleshu Kadachana" consisting of two *pādas* appears in the Bhagavad Gita. If there's a better word please feel free to edit it in.]

Comment: I'd still rather see "In this book, one verse reads "Vadhikaraste ma phaleshu," meaning it is your duty to help others. The connector *or* tells me that the book might have English in it, which you quote. Or you don't know which quote was in the book.

Comment: It may simply be a dialectal difference. Perhaps a comma before *or* would help. Using *or* to indicate a translation is hardly new: OED has *or* in this "same thing" or "that is" sense as early as 1357.

Comment: AL's answer is perfect, but I do perfectly agree with the comment by Yosef.  Many things are somewhat common in writing, but a very bad idea.